# angular and ui-router start app with default (pre defined) route

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm having a simple blog application. I defined some states for the routing and also defined that on each state-change event it will check the authentication level (in a very naive manner for now) and if the user is allowed to go to this state or not.

```
app.run(function($rootScope, $state, UserService){
$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams){
    if (!UserService.getCurrentUser()){
        $state.go('app.login');
    }
});
```

My JS entry point include this configuration:

```
app.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider){

    $stateProvider.state('app', {
        url: '',
        abstract: true
    });
});
```

I want that when ever going into my application the main route will be the blogs "feed" (and of course when trying to get there it will also fire the $stateChangeStart event so that the authentication will be verified.
How can I achive that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `otherwise` method:

```
app.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider){

    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/feed');

    $stateProvider.state('app', {
        url: '',
        abstract: true
    });
});
```

Don't forget that `/feed` must also be defined with `$stateProvider.state`

Comment: I think that in this way the $stateChangesStart is not fired and therefore the function that is checking if the user is authenticated is not getting called.

Comment: Use $urlRouterProvider more and load your state when /feed like this
app.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider){
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/feed');
    $urlRouterProvider.when('/feed','your state configuration');
    $stateProvider.state('app', {
        url: '',
        abstract: true
    });
});
So it will fire your event,too.